# How do I display all numbers that end with the number 3 with a for loop in java?

Tags: java

I need to write a for loop in java that displays all of the numbers ranging from 13 - 93 that end in the number 3.  It must include 13 and 93.

Comment: Please read:  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2):

Loop from `13` to `93`. Increment by `10`. Like,

```
for (int i = 13; i <= 93; i += 10) {
    // Print the value
}
```

Comment: Of all the answers in SO, this by far is the most efficient one I have seen.

Comment: @papaya I try to keep it [short and to the point](https://askubuntu.com/a/439765/214223).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted, you could write a function that achieves this task but with parameters
that allow for more flexible control. Where it takes in arguments representing a
from value and a to value, and something like a endsWith value. It's just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Any decimal based number mod 10 will get you the last digit.

```
    for (int i = start ; i <= end ; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 3) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```